# How is gas price too low corrected (truffle deploy)?

Tags: truffle

truffle.js

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8540,
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 4600000,
gasPrice: 4000000   // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

> <       "code": -32010,  <       "message": "Transaction gas price is
>   too low. There is another transaction with same nonce in the queue.
>   Try increasing the gas price or incrementing the nonce."  <     },  < 
>   "id": 6  <   }

I am using parity.

How would I know what gas price should be used, or how is the nonce changed?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not really the gas price but the nonce of the transaction.

It is saying that there is already a transaction waiting to be mined with the exact same nonce. You must increase the nonce of your transaction. I recommand you to read the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

The gas price message is just saying that it cannot accept this transaction because it should have a superior gas price than the other one to be considered as the correct one.

Comment: How can I change the nounce? I just use truffle migrate. Is there an option for nouce?

Comment: Can I delete the pending txns?

Answer (score 0):

Use --no-persistent-txqueue in the start of the node to remove the old txn.